# Mongodb replica set permission denied on arbiter heartbeat

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to set up a mongo db replicaset, working with Mongodb 3.4.

ServerA:

- srv1:27017 - primary
- arb:27027 - arbiter

ServerB:

- srv2:27017 - secondary

arb shouldn't be hosted with srv1 on ServerA, plan to move later.

The server ports are open, connecting mongo shell works on all instances.

Running `rs.status()` on srv1 shows everything is fine.

Running it on srv2, however, shows:

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : "ServerA:27027",
    "health" : 0,
    "state" : 8,
    "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
    "uptime" : 0,
    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-11-17T14::36:48.088Z"),
    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Permission denied",
    "configVersion" : -1
}
```

for the arbiter section (the rest are fine).
The logs on srv2 are repeating these three lines:

```
2017-11-17T09:19:02.758-0500 | ASIO [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to ServerA:27027 - HostUnreachable: Permission denied
2017-11-17T09:19:02.758-0500 | ASIO [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Dropping all pooled connections to ServerA:27027 due to failed operation on a connection
2017-11-17T09:19:02.758-0500 | REPL [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to ServerA:27027; HostUnreachable: Permission denied
```

None of them have any authentication set, and srv1, which is hosted on the same machine has no heartbeat problem with the arbiter. Srv2 has no heartbeat problem with srv1.
Googling around, I've seen people not being able to connect because of ip addresses not being bound in mongod.config, or being firewalled, but that's not the case here.

Comment: srv1 and arb share the same host, so the chances are they try to communicate via local loopback. Could you confirm servers listen on both interfaces?

Comment: I tried connecting a mongo shell from ServerB to ServerA:27017 and ServerA:27027, and that works fine. Also, srv2 shows no issues with srv1 in the replica set, only with arb. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Does `telnet serv1 27027` form serv 2 work?

Comment: Telnet does indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out SELinux was preventing communication on 27027. I guess mongo shell and telnet have no policies preventing tcp traffic. I think ServerA doesn't have any issues because both mongo instances are on the same host.

So in addition to allowing 27017, i had to allow 27027 as well:

```
semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27027
```

If you don't care about added security, another solution is to disable SELinux altogether.

It looks like that if you're running a replica set on servers that have SELinux, you need to allow all ports that are used between members of the replica set.

This is running RedHat 7.4, other distros might ship with different policies.